# Parse a collection of XML files to generate synthesis report

Tags: xml, xpath, wildcard, xslt-2.0

I have to generate reports based on a collection of xml files.
Everyday some stats are extracted from a system and I would like to generate an HTML report that reads all xml input file (identified by a mask like "Daily Request*.xml") in the current directory.

Exemple of "Daily Request file": Daily Request Extract_20130205-130822.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tasks startDate="2013/02/04 13:08:21" endDate="2013/02/05 13:08:21" environment="Q000">
  <task create="2013/02/04 20:44:15" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="TUAJW1W0" mode="Batch" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="633.44" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:18:36" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="true" status="Completed" duration="48.35" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:19:21" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="17.36" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:19:21" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="2.93" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:19:26" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="true" status="Completed" duration="9.57" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:19:34" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="8.67" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:19:34" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="2.95" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:21:23" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="true" status="Completed" duration="7.87" />
  <task create="2013/02/05 08:21:30" type="deliverDistrib" jobName="LVAJW1W0" mode="Online" synch="false" status="Completed" duration="5.87" />
</tasks>
```

I have read in doc and some example that we can use the function document() retrieve external files. But apparently it does not support wildcard.
I found another thread saying that we have to use the Xpath function: **collection()**

Something like

```
collection('file:///./?select=Daily*.xml')
```

I would like to start beeing abble to concat all  element in a stream so that I can write the report from them.

My proposed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///./?select=Daily*.xml')/tasks">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But id does not output anything :-/

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I get it apparently with this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('./?select=Daily*.xml')/tasks">
     <xsl:copy-of select="task"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```